# image picker and store them into firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add this future to my app so I wrote this code

```
 PickedFile _image;
  String _uploadedFileURL;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
Future getImage(bool isCamera) async {
    PickedFile image;
    if (isCamera) {
      PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      setState(() {
        _image = image;
      });
    } else
      PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

but how to uploaded it in flutter ? I searched a lot but in every code I found there is a mistake because of the updated and in the storage package example I did not find uploading image so, what the last code to upload images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have been using for selecting the image from image picker then cropping the picked image and then later on uploading it into firebase storage. Hope this helps you. Any clarifications needed please comment.

```
    // Crop Selected Image
    Future _cropImage(File selectedFile) async {
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: selectedFile.path,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(
          ratioX: 1.0,
          ratioY: 1.0,
        ),
        cropStyle: CropStyle.circle,
      );
      if (cropped != null) {
        setState(
          () {
            _imageFile = cropped;
          },
        );
      }
    }

    // Select Image Via Image Picker
    Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
      if (selected != null) {
        _cropImage(selected);
      }
    }

    // Upload Picture to Firebase
    Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
      String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
      Reference firebaseStorageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
      UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
      // ignore: unused_local_variable
      TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the image from gallery(modify as per your need):-

```
selectImageFromGallery() async
      {
        final picker=ImagePicker();
        setState(() {
          inProcess=true;
        });
        final imageFile= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        if(imageFile!=null)
        {
          _image=File(imageFile.path);
        }
        setState(() {
          inProcess=false;
        });
      }
```

And to upload use the below code:-

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File image) async
  {
    String downloadURL;
    String postId=DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images").child("post_$postId.jpg");
    await ref.putFile(image);
    downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }
```

to save data:-

```
saveData()async
{
String url=await uploadFile(_image);//to upload and store the url
//rest code to save to firestore.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Slightly off-topic: Upload image picker file to Google Cloud SQL / AWS PostgresQL, after converting it to bytes

I can only help you on the side related to uploading image picker files converted to byte to PostgresQL.

I upload image as bytes to my PostgresQL DB, in the functions below I gather all the PickedFile and I upload them all at once while generating unique UID. Once they have been uploaded I save their uid to link them to the user who uploaded.

See the code below:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

final Random _random = Random.secure();

// generate uid for your image
String createCryptoSecureId([int length = 32]) {
  var values = List<int>.generate(length ~/ 1.3, (i) => _random.nextInt(256));

  return base64Url.encode(values);
}
// works with list of PickedFile
Future<String> uploadImagesToPSQL(final List<PickedFile> imageFileList) async {
  List<Uint8List> imageBytesList = [];
  for (PickedFile imageFile in imageFileList) {
    File file = File(imageFile.path);
    if (file != null) {
      Uint8List imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
      print(imageBytes);
      imageBytesList.add(imageBytes);
    }
  }

  String sqlQuery =
      "INSERT INTO myimages(id, image) VALUES (@id, decode(@image, 'hex'))";

  PostgreSQLConnection connection = await initConnectionPSQL('update'); // can't share as there is sensitive code.

  List<String> imageIds;
  final futures = <Future>[];
  for (var imageBytes in imageBytesList) {
    String imageId = createCryptoSecureId(32);
    imageIds.add(imageId);
    var substitutionValues = {"id": imageIds, "image": hex.encode(imageBytes)};
    futures.add(
        connection.execute(sqlQuery, substitutionValues: substitutionValues));
  }

  await Future.wait(futures);

  return imageIds.join();
}
```

NB: This is test code, ideally you want to use a REST api that has secure access to your DB.